# Erro Unity Desenvolvimento de um projeto Online

Tags: c#, unity3d, script

Como eu conserto esse erro?

> Assets/Online/Online.cs(139,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `PlayerBehaviour' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Meu *script* esta da segunte maneira

```
PlayerBehaviour player = FindObjectOfType(typeof(PlayerBehaviour)) as PlayerBehaviour;
```

A versão do meu  Unity é **4.3.2f1**

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa adicionar a referência ao *namespace* em que sua classe `PlayerBehaviour` está na classe `Online`.

Ex.:

```
using umNamespace;

public class Online {...}
```